# Access query to find next maintenance cycle

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a weird query. I am creating a vehicle maintenance database. Each vehicle has different maintenance cycles at 250, 500, 1000, and 2000. so when a user pulls up to a vehicle and enters the mileage it needs to know what is the next maintenance cycle.

Here is an example. so the vehicle would have 1150 miles the next cycle would be 1250. I have a table that says there are 250, 500, 1000, and 2000 cycles but I don't have anything for the 1250 or 1500 or 1750 because they are the same as 250... so it would need to pick the 250 maintenance cycle and then over 1250, it would need to show that 1500 is the next cycle and so on.

So what would I do to pick the next maintenance cycle?

Here is some data:

```
250 Cycle
500 Cycle
1000 Cycle
2000 Cycle
```

a user pulls up to a vehicle with 850 cycles, how do I pick the 1000 in this case but then also if a user pulls up to a vehicle with 1050, it would need to pick the 250 cycle (because there is no 1250 cycle).

Comment: Why wouldn't your hypothetical vehicle with 550 cycles next maintenance cycle be 250? You don't have a 750 maintenance cycle either.

Comment: Are you contradicting yourself: *the next cycle would be 1250*... *because there is no 1250 cycle* ?

Comment: @jac, yes nice catch.  I will correct that.

Comment: @Parfait, huh? it says the next cycle would be 250 because there is no 1250.

Comment: @djblois - Read your second paragraph claiming there is a 1250 cycle.

Comment: So you do have a 1250 cycle. You should either register all possible cycles or only use the 250 cycle and do some calculation is your query. Anyway, your request is pretty vague (and that's an understatement) and so are your examples.....

Comment: I believe the question is more like a car maintenance schedule. The 250 cycle maintenance needs to be performed every 250 cycles. At 1000 cycles the 250 cycle maintenance is performed, plus the extra maintenance defined for 1000 cycles. There is no defined 1250 cycle maintenance so just the 250 cycle maintenance needs to be performed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Access it is much simpler to create a function:

```
Public Function NextCycle(ByVal Mileage As Long) As Long

    Dim rst         As DAO.Recordset

    Dim SQL         As String
    Dim Cycle       As Long
    Dim ThisCycle   As Long
    Dim NextService As Long

    SQL = "Select Cycle From Cycles Order By 1"
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)

    Cycle = rst!Cycle.Value
    While Not rst.EOF
        ThisCycle = rst!Cycle.Value
        NextService = -Int(-Mileage / ThisCycle) * ThisCycle
        If NextService - Mileage < Cycle Then
            Cycle = ThisCycle
        End If
        Debug.Print Mileage, ThisCycle, NextService, NextService - Mileage, Cycle
        rst.MoveNext
    Wend
    rst.Close

    Set rst = Nothing

    NextCycle = Cycle

End Function
```

Example results:

```
? NextCycle(850)
 850           250           1000          150           250 
 850           500           1000          150           500 
 850           1000          1000          150           1000 
 850           2000          2000          1150          1000 
 1000 

? NextCycle(1050)
 1050          250           1250          200           250 
 1050          500           1500          450           250 
 1050          1000          2000          950           250 
 1050          2000          2000          950           250 
 250 

? NextCycle(10850)
 10850         250           11000         150           250 
 10850         500           11000         150           500 
 10850         1000          11000         150           1000 
 10850         2000          12000         1150          1000 
 1000
```

Comment: A cowardly downvoter I see. If you don't understand the answer, speak up and I will explain.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. This is in SQL. If you are using MS Access you will have to translate because I don't have MS Access. This sample creates and populates a temp table variable. It then gets the difference between a current cycles figure and the next larger cycle. Then in the case statement it uses the difference to select the next smaller cycle from the temp table. If there is no smaller cycle available it returns the next cycle larger than the current cycle value.

Note that I haven't done the work to handle wrap around, where your current cycle is larger than the largest value in the table.

```
DECLARE @CurrCycle int = 749

DECLARE @Temp TABLE
(
    Cycle int
)

INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (250)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (500)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (1000)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (2000)

DECLARE @Difference int

SET @Difference = 
(
    SELECT 
        TOP 1 (Temp1.Cycle - @CurrCycle)
    FROM
        @Temp Temp1
    WHERE
        (Temp1.Cycle >= @CurrCycle)
)

SELECT (CASE
    WHEN
        (SELECT TOP 1 Cycle FROM @Temp WHERE Cycle <= @Difference) IS NOT NULL THEN (SELECT TOP 1 Cycle FROM @Temp WHERE Cycle <= @Difference ORDER BY Cycle DESC)
    ELSE
        (SELECT TOP 1 Cycle FROM @Temp WHERE Cycle >= @CurrCycle)
END)
```

Comment: MS Access does use SQL. You are referring to the dialect, specifically TSQL used in SQL Server and not MS Access' Jet/ACE SQL. Your solution may not be feasible as OP may not know how to translate a stored procedure into an Access application.

Comment: @Parfait I know how to create Stored Procedures in SQL server, as I am pretty proficient in it but I am lost on how to translate it into Access, which I am also pretty proficient in.

Answer (score 0):

```
 [cycle]*(1+Int([miles]/[cycle]))
```

This will give the next cycle, assuming they occur evenly.  If the cycle is always 250, you can use that in place of the variable.